# ActiveMQ Artemis not displaying the web console when run in Docker

Tags: docker, activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

I am deploying the ActiveMQ Artemis in Docker from the [quay.io](https://artemiscloud.io/docs/tutorials/deploybasicimage/) using docker desktop in my local machine (using Windows 10).

I issued below command to start the latest image:

```
docker run -e AMQ_USER=admin -e AMQ_PASSWORD=admin -p8161:8161 -p61616:61616 -p5672:5672 --rm --name artemis quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
```

Note: dev.latest tag is not available, so used the latest tag.

The ActiveMQ Artemis instance in the Docker container starts successfully, and I'm able to login to the web console:

```
...
2022-06-18 20:08:26,820 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2022-06-18 20:08:26,821 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.22.0 [broker, nodeID=68f4db2b-ef42-11ec-b609-0242ac110002]
2022-06-18 20:08:27,607 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2022-06-18 20:08:27,746 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2022-06-18 20:08:28,414 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2022-06-18 20:08:28,438 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2022-06-18 20:08:28,443 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.14.2
2022-06-18 20:08:28,459 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "admin" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2022-06-18 20:08:28,480 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginRedirectFilter] Hawtio loginRedirectFilter is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2022-06-18 20:08:28,520 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2022-06-18 20:08:28,539 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/home/jboss/broker/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2022-06-18 20:08:28,788 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://172.17.0.2:8161
2022-06-18 20:08:28,789 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://172.17.0.2:8161/console/jolokia
2022-06-18 20:08:28,790 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://172.17.0.2:8161/console
2022-06-18 20:14:28,681 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2022-06-18 20:14:30,401 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.keycloak.KeycloakServlet] Keycloak integration is disabled
2022-06-18 20:14:34,273 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Logging in user: admin
```

I am unable to view the Consumer, Producer, Sessions, Queues, etc tags.

I understand that we need to modify the IPs in `jolokia-access.xml` and restart, but I can't edit the file within `docker exec -it artemis bash` within the image and restart it if executed without `--rm` in Docker run command.

Is there any envrionment variable to disable cors or strict in `jolokia-access.xml`?

Below is what I see at `http://localhost:8161/console`:

[image: blank web console]

The log indicates that the console is available at `http://172.17.0.2:8161/console`. However, this is not accessible since the docker is totally a different network. When I try to access it I get below message:

```
This site can’t be reached 172.17.0.2 took too long to respond
```

And when I access the end point `http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia` I get the message:

```
{ error_type: "java.lang.Exception", error: "java.lang.Exception : Origin null is not allowed to call this agent", status: 403 }
```

Comment: `http://172.17.0.2:8161/console` is not accessible, since the docker is totally a different network. I get below message 
`This site can’t be reached
172.17.0.2 took too long to respond`

Comment: When i access the end point `http://localhost:8161/console/jolokia` i get the message ```{
error_type: "java.lang.Exception",
error: "java.lang.Exception : Origin null is not allowed to call this agent",
status: 403
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bypass the jolokia in the docker,

- I created a reverse proxy using nginx server in the docker and set the headers.

Below is the steps I followed,

- Run an nginx instance,

```
> docker run -d --name nginx-proxy -p 80:80 nginx
```

- copy the existing `default.conf` to local system, using below command

```
# my present working directory is a temp folder 
> docker cp nginx-proxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf .
```

- Identified the hostname/ip address of the aretmis container, since i need to set this to the header of Origin

```
> docker exec artemis hostname -i
```

- Updated below content to the `default.conf` file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header Origin http://172.17.0.2;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 86400;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204; break;
     }

     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header Origin http://172.17.0.2;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header Origin http://172.17.0.2;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
     }

      proxy_pass http://172.17.0.2:8161/;
      proxy_set_header Origin http://172.17.0.2;
      proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
     error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
     location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
     }
}
```

- Note: don't forget the `;` at the end.
- copy the default to the nginx server, we can validate and reload the new config without stopping the container.

```
# I am in my temp directory 
# to copy use below command
> docker cp default.conf nginx-proxy:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# to validate the config file use below command
> docker exec nginx-proxy nginx -t

# to restart send singal using below command
> docker exec nginx-proxy nginx -r reload
```

- Since we are exposing the 80 port for the nginx container, we can hit the `http://localhost:80/console` to access the ArtemisMQ page.
- This can be use only for Development purpose. Not suitable for production.

[image: Artemis console view]

[Refered How to set nginx reverse proxy blog](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Docker-Nginx-reverse-proxy-setup-example)

Additional Note:

- I had to validate whether i am able to access the jolokia endpoint from within the the nginx server of docker, used below command.

```
> docker exec -it nginx-proxy bash
```

The `curl` command I used to verify.

```
root@681b68921481:/# curl -H "Origin: http://172.17.0.2" http://admin:amdin@172.17.0.2:8161/console/jolokia/
```

- Output:

```
{"request":{"type":"version"},"value":{"agent":"1.7.0","protocol":"7.2","config":{"listenForHttpService":"true","authIgnoreCerts":"false","agentId":"172.17.0.2-1-6c008c24-servlet","debug":"fal
se","agentType":"servlet","policyLocation":"file:\/home\/jboss\/broker\/etc\/jolokia-access.xml","agentContext":"\/jolokia","serializeException":"false","mimeType":"text\/plain","dispatcherCla
sses":"org.jolokia.http.Jsr160ProxyNotEnabledByDefaultAnymoreDispatcher","multicastGroup":"239.192.48.84","authMode":"basic","authMatch":"any","streaming":"true","canonicalNaming":"true","hist
oryMaxEntries":"10","allowErrorDetails":"false","allowDnsReverseLookup":"true","realm":"jolokia","includeStackTrace":"false","multicastPort":"24884","mbeanQualifier":"qualifier=hawtio","useRes
```

Comment: a very small correction : to reload nginx 
nginx -s reload
not -r

Comment: this solution did not work for me

Answer (score 4):

I solved creating a custom script [launch.sh](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vifito/36b00547251ab84225d986fd7d4f18f3) to override launcher in the image `quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker` and disable CORS limitation to works web console runnig at docker.

```bash
# Download script
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/vifito/36b00547251ab84225d986fd7d4f18f3/raw -O launch.sh

# Set exec permission
chmod +x launch.sh

# docker run
docker run -d --name amq \
  -e AMQ_USER=admin -e AMQ_PASSWORD=admin \
  -p 8161:8161 -p 61616:61616 \
  -v `pwd`/launch.sh:/opt/amq/bin/launch.sh \
  quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker

# Open console
xdg-open http://0.0.0.0:8161/console
```

Comment: Did this solution worked for you so that you managed to see console?

Comment: this worked for me but just the url that succeded to open console ;
http://localhost:8161/console

Answer (score 0):

ArtemisCloud broker containers restrict access to the container network for security reasons but Docker Desktop for Windows doesn't support the [host networking driver](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/).

You could overwriting the default broker config mounting your own `etc` folder on `/home/jboss/broker/etc`, i.e.

```
docker run -v /tmp/my-broker-etc:/home/jboss/broker/etc -e AMQ_USER=admin -e AMQ_PASSWORD=admin -p8161:8161 -p61616:61616 -p5672:5672 --rm --name artemis quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
```

Docker makes deploying microservice applications very easy but it has some limitations for a production environment. I would take a look to the ArtemisCloud.io operator that provide a way to deploy the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Broker on Kubernetes.

Comment: This didn't work either, when adding a volume to that `/etc/jboss/broker/etc`, the launch.sh was not able to identify the artemis shell, so it fails to start the container. I found a way using proxy, added it as an answer, it helps.